# df.columns returns RangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

When I print out the columns in my df like so

```
user_df=pd.DataFrame(user)
    print(user_df.columns)
```

the output is `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12, step=1)`, instead of the column names `['phone','unique phone numbers','group','County','PNC/ANC','Facility Name','Date of enrollmnet']`.

What I am missing? How can I solve this?

Comment: How/where do you read your data from Excel-file into pandas? And how does your data look like? Looks like your df doesn't have headers assigned but just indexes.

Comment: @JvdV
my data is in a google sheet
```userlist_wb=gc.open_by_key('key').worksheet('masteruser') 

user=userlist_wb.get_all_values()
```

Comment: @JvdV
looks like this  >>> https://imgur.com/a/V5lWreg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, looks like your data doesn't have headers assigned, so therefor returning `RangeIndex`. Try the following instead:

```
userlist_wb = gc.open_by_key('key').worksheet('masteruser')
user = userlist_wb.get_all_values()
headers = user.pop(0)
user_df = pd.DataFrame(user, columns=headers)
print(user_df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "user" object is a DataFrame with headers, you can

```
user_df.columns = user.columns
```

In this way, when

```
print(user_df.columns)
```

you can get

> ['phone','unique phone numbers','group','County','PNC/ANC','Facility Name','Date of enrollmnet'].